# vertical align link inside div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've created some floating buttons and a link that fills the whole button.  However, vertical alignment doesn't seem to apply - the link text always stays at the top of the button `<li>`.

Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/su7nf/

---

```
<div id="ButtonContainer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">Report an Issue</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">Enter Project</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">Request Consultation</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="TemplateButton"><a href="http://www.google.com">How to Protect Yourself From Some Really Long Text</a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    /* BUTTONS INSIDE TAB STYLING */

    #ButtonContainer {
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #ButtonContainer > ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
    }

    #ButtonContainer > ul > li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .TemplateButton {
        overflow: auto;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .TemplateButton > a {
        width: 119px;
        height: 119px;
        padding: 15px;
        float: left;
        background-color: pink;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    }
```

Comment: If you had a single word or single line of text in those buttons, you could easily align them using `line-height:119px;`. But since it's multiline, it's more difficult. Take a look at this link: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `a` tags use `table-cell` instead of `float` and change vertical-align to `middle`:

```
.TemplateButton > a {
  /*float: left; Remove this*/
  display:table-cell;    /*Add this*/
  vertical-align:middle; /*Change to middle*/
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su7nf/8/)**

Comment: The float was completely pointless, no idea why it was there.  Didn't know it trumped display like that though, good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3280943 np mate glad to help you

Answer (score 8):

Set the anchor's `line-height` to that of the DIV, or set it to `display: block` otherwise your width/height values won't work

Comment: Can't vote yet. But I would have voted for helion3 answer. display:table-cell; Always causes problems for me down the line. it will also lock the size of the link to the size of the parent element, which can be a pain.